# NuxtLink to="/" returns "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: String contains an invalid character"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-router, nuxtjs3

After 4 hours of anger I've finally got a Proof of concept for using nuxt 3, strapi 4, and graphql, to make a blog, my only issue now is that for some god forsaken reason my link to the home page isn't working, here is the code for `[slug].vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="bg-white py-24 sm:py-32">
    <NuxtLink to="/" class="text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">home</NuxtLink>
    {{ postData.title }}
    {{ postData.description }}
    {{ postData.body }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import gql from "graphql-tag";
const route = useRoute();

const postSlug = route.params.slug;

// console.log(postSlug);

// apollo query

const getArticleBySlug = gql`
  query getArticleBySlug($slug: String!) {
    articles(filters: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          slug
          description
          body
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(
  getArticleBySlug,
  {
    slug: postSlug,
  },
  { lazy: true }
);

const postData = data.value.articles.data[0].attributes;

console.log(postData);
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Here is the code for `index.vue`:

```html
    <template>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="bg-black" v-for="article in test.data" v-bind="article.id">    <h1 class="text-black text-4xl">
            {{ article.attributes.title || 'Loading...' }}
        </h1>
      <p>{{ article.attributes.description}}</p>
      <p>{{ article.attributes.body}}</p>
      <NuxtLink :to="article.attributes.slug" class="link">Read</NuxtLink>
      
    </div>
    
    
    
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import gql from 'graphql-tag';
    
    
    const query = gql`
      query allArticlesQuery {
        articles {
          data {
            id
            attributes {
              title
              slug
              description
              body
              date
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
    // set an object data as the resust of the query
    // use the useAsyncQuery hook to fetch the data
    
    const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(query )
    
    
    // give the data a name
    const test = data.value.articles 
    // console.log(test);
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    
    </style>
```

On the first click, I get this message.
 `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: String contains an invalid character`

On the second click I get these

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core 
  at <RouteProvider key="/" vnode= 
Object { __v_isVNode: true, __v_skip: true, type: {…}, props: {…}, key: null, ref: {…}, scopeId: null, slotScopeIds: null, children: null, component: null, … }
 route= 
Object { fullPath: "/", path: "/", query: {}, hash: "", name: "index", params: {}, matched: (1) […], meta: Proxy, redirectedFrom: undefined, href: "/" }
  ... > 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot> deps:1449:13
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: node is null
    NuxtJS 66
```

Some things I have tried:

1. change `to="/"` to `to="http://localhost:3000"`

   1. Works as expected
2. change `to="/"` to `:to="{path: '/' }"`

   1. Did not work
3. change `to="/"` to `{name: 'index'}"`

   1. Did not work
4. Remove query from `index.vue`

   1. Works but I'm no longer able to see all posts

I just want to click the link and get back to the home page, please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use the `name` prop?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That didn't work either, I did some more testing yesterday before I rage quit, and it seems to be related to the query in `index.vue`, removing the query allows the page to load just fine.